# How to turn from large to small title with animation

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to change the navigation bar from large to small title with animation on the same controller when tapping a button for example? Now I tried to set:

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

But it does not support to have the animation. Please give a help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, hope it will work for you.

```
let fadeTextAnimation = CATransition()
fadeTextAnimation.duration = 0.5
fadeTextAnimation.type = .fade
    
navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.add(fadeTextAnimation, forKey: "fadeText")
navigationItem.title = "Testing"
```

Comment: when I tap on the button, the navigation bar will be turned from large to small title with animation like scrolling up the scroll view